# Flutter Stream listen does not work properly

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is listening to a stream which contains Lists of Events for each day of month.

I need this for my TableCalendar Widget

I want to count each Event of each list of the stream and display it in the calendar.

For this I wrote this function:

```
  countEvents(DateTime datetime) {
    eventBloc.getEventsOfDay(datetime).listen((event) {
      counter = event.length;
    });
  }
```

This is where I execute the function (in markerBuilder):

```
 StreamBuilder<List<Event>>(
              stream: selectedEvents,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final events = snapshot.data;
                  groupEvents(allEventsList);
                  return Column(children: [
                    Card(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: TableCalendar(
                        firstDay: DateTime.utc(1970, 01, 01),
                        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2999, 12, 31),
                        focusedDay: _selectedDay,
                        locale: 'en_US',
                        onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                          _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                        },
                        selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                          return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
                        },
                        headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppColors.red,
                          ),
                          headerMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        ),
                        calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(),
                        calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                            markerBuilder: ((context, day, events) {
                          countEvents(day);
                          return Container(
                            width: 20,
                            height: 15,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: AppColors.red,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                            child: Text(counter.toString()),
                          );
                        })),
                        //Day Changed
                        onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay) {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedDay = selectDay;
                            _focusedDay = focusDay;
                            selectedEvents =
                                eventBloc.getEventsOfDay(_selectedDay);
                          });
                          //print(_focusedDay);
                        },
                        startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                        eventLoader: getEventsForDay,
                      ),
```

`counter` is a global variable for the class

I used the debugger and it seems like the listen function is skipped all the time..

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you share more code?

Comment: I added some code @selimdogan